# IdentityServer4 With a Separate Login Screen

Tags: identityserver4

I have to implement a client that has its own Login Web Page into our current IdentityServer4 implementation.

I expect the only way to accomplish this is by using the Resource Owner Password flow.

I just want to double check with the experts here to see if there is another way to use the client's existing Login Page with IdentityServer.

Comment: Why can't you use the IS4 login page?

Comment: Be very careful with the ROPF. In general it is highly not recommended, unless you own both - the authentication server and the client using ROPF. Then it is someway forgivable, but still.. 

You have to know, that you can customize your IDS4 login page per client and return different screens for different client.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg, requirements from the actual client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are correct, just make sure you understand the concerns when using resource owner credentials flow, especially since it looks like this flow is going to be implemented by a 3rd party app in your case.